# asp.net core nuget packet manager does not install packages

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, visual-studio

I am trying to install any packets * from package manager console but I have the below issues:

*

```
Install-Package Ninject -version 3.0.1.10 -projectname SportsStore.WebUI
Install-Package Ninject.Web.Common -version 3.0.0.7 -projectname SportsStore.WebUI
Install-Package Ninject.MVC3 -Version 3.0.0.6 -projectname SportsStore.WebUI
Install-Package Ninject -version 3.0.1.10 -projectname SportsStore.UnitTests
Install-Package Ninject.Web.Common -version 3.0.0.7 -projectname SportsStore.UnitTests
Install-Package Ninject.MVC3 -Version 3.0.0.6 -projectname SportsStore.UnitTests
Install-Package Moq -version 4.1.1309.1617 -projectname SportsStore.WebUI
Install-Package Moq -version 4.1.1309.1617 -projectname SportsStore.UnitTests
Install-Package Microsoft.Aspnet.Mvc -version 5.0.0 -projectname SportsStore.Domain
Install-Package Microsoft.Aspnet.Mvc -version 5.0.0 -projectname SportsStore.UnitTests
```

Issue problems (example):

```
At line:1 char:1
+ Install-Package Ninject -version 3.0.1.10 -projectname SportsStore.WebUI
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (SportsStore.WebUI:String) [Install-Package], ItemNotFoundException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : NuGetProjectNotFound,NuGet.PackageManagement.PowerShellCmdlets.InstallPackageCommand
```

What can I do to solve the problem? My Visual Studio is the Community version 2015. Windows 8.1 operation system.

Comment: Just make sure `SportsStore.WebUI` is selected in the Default Project drop down in Pasckage Manager console and try e.g `Install-Package Ninject -version 3.0.1.10` without the `-projectname ...`

Comment: Ok thank you for the solution.